# parameterise table name in nested repeaters datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, sqldatasource

i want to select a column like cl1 from different tables for each row on gridview and show it on my repeater. how can i do this?

here is my code:

```
<asp:gridview cssclass="text-center table table-bordered table-condensed" id="GridView1" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False" datakeynames="PID" datasourceid="SqlDataSource2" emptydatatext="There are no data records to display.">
<Columns>                                
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="مشخصات اختصاصی">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="CatPageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("catpage").ToString().Replace(".aspx","") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Repeater ID="SecondPageRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="SecondPageSqlDataSource">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("cl1") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SecondPageSqlDataSource" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DrB_DBConnectionString %>' SelectCommand='select cl1 from @dest where cl1=3'>
                <SelectParameters>                        
                    <asp:ControlParameter  Name="dest" ControlID="CatPageLabel"/>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

and this is the error:

```
Invalid object name '@dest'.
```

thank you

Comment: Where did you define `@dest` ?

Comment: `<asp:ControlParameter  Name="dest" ControlID="CatPageLabel"/>`

Comment: Isn't it because you've defined your object after calling the query?

Comment: i think i have to use dynamic sql or  use PROCEDURE